# Defining static const value form a struct

Tags: c, struct, static, constants

I am using C99 in Keil to program a microprocessor, and having difficulty using a struct to define a static const.
The following compliles without issue:

```
static uint8_t const addr1 = 0x76;
static uint8_t const addr = addr1;
```

However the following does not:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t const           address;    
} bmp280_t;

static bmp280_t bmp280_0 = {
        .address    =   0x76,
    };

static uint8_t const addr2 = bmp280_0.address;
```

The last line causes a compilation error:

> ......\main.c(97): error:  #28: expression must have a constant
>   value   static uint8_t const addr2 = bmp280_0.address;

I have tried to replicate in visual studio, but both cases do not compile.  I don't know if that is because it is compiling as cpp or using a different standard..

Comment: If first one compiled fine, then it's using a compiler extension. Constant variables cannot be used for initialization in standard C.

Comment: Ok, I thought it might be something like that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The initializer you are using (i.e.: `bmp280_0.address`) is not a *compile-time constant*. You can however do the following:

```
#define ADDRESS 0x76   

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t const           address;    
} bmp280_t;

static bmp280_t bmp280_0 = {
        .address    =   ADDRESS,
    };

static uint8_t const addr2 = ADDRESS;
```

That is, define a preprocessor macro `ADDRESS` which will result in the compile-time constant `0x76` when replaced by the preprocessor and use this preprocessor macro as initializer.